# Are there significant differences between the Xbox and Wii versions of LEGO Star Wars III: The Clone Wars?

Tags: version-differences, lego-star-wars-3-the-clone-wars

Apart from the price :) *and the quality of the graphics* are there any significant differences between the versions of the game on the different consoles.

Having access to both a 360 and Wii I could get either, but can't decide which to go for.

Just to repeat I'm not interested in hearing that the 360 has "better" graphics - given the relative power of each console I can work that one out for myself. What I'm interested in are whether one version has more levels, more characters to unlock etc.

I've done some research but most of the posts seem to be about differences between the 3DS version and the "full" console version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't played Lego Clone Wars but for the past games (Harry Potter, Indiana Jones, etc) they have been identical.  The only differences were the achievements on Xbox.  If you don't care about the graphical differences then there is really no difference.  Plus with the Xbox version you are not stuck using that clunky WiiMote :)

If you look at the strategy guides, there seem to be no sections indicating different content for the Wii and are all labelled as applying to all three systems.

My conclusion is they are the same except no achievements and some controls mapped to Wii's motion controls.  Nothing content wise.

Comment: Regarding the Wiimote, Jedi characters can throw their lightsaber. This is done by holding down a button + moving the left stick on the Xbox. I think this is done by moving the Wiimote on the Wii version, which might be easier to aim with.