# Is there a functional difference between the console and PC versions of the LEGO games?

Tags: pc, version-differences

I'm wondering if there are any different play areas (added or missing) between the PC editions of the LEGO games (Star Wars, Indiana Jones, Harry Potter, etc) and their console equivalents.

I'm also curious if saving to a hard drive on the PC conveys any extra part sharing modes?  If the games themselves do not offer this feature, is there a 3rd party editor that helps with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't play any XBox 360 or PS3 versions, but a fast research on various sources like forums and play-through sites make me state that there are no gameplay/content differences between the different editions.

The only differences seems to be:

- Command binding / Peripheral Support
- More graphic settings available on PC version
- Implementation of XBox 360 Achievements and PS3 Trophies (No Steam achievements unfortunately, and that is a real pity for me)

There is also a similar answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19839/are-there-significant-differences-between-the-xbox-and-wii-versions-of-lego-star) on Gaming.SE

Comment: I had looked at the linked to answer before posting :)

Answer (score 3):

All consoles are the same as the PC version. Apart from the graphics, all platforms are the same except for DS which has fewer areas.